# Unable to resolve Class for burningimage plugin in grails app

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm running grails 2.0.4 on a mac, and installed the burningimage plugin to handle image uploads.

I have this at in my domain object:

```
import pl.burningice.plugins.image.ast.FileImageContainer
```

however, netbeans says it's unable to resolve the class, and when I call imageUploadService in my controller, I get this error

```
No such property: imageUploadService for class: wine.WineController
```

Netbeans believes the plugin is installed, and I can see the plugin source files under the project in the .grails folder. Any idea how to resolve the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `grails clean` and recompile might help it see the class.  However I get these type of import 'errors' in Netbeans but everything compiles and runs fine.

Try injecting the service in your controller:

```
class WineController {
   def imageUploadService
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I believe adding the def imageUploadService fixed the problem.